# Wordpress permalink doesnot work even after changing the value, updating manually or editing apache config

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I am deploying a wordpress site [Application made using CMS feature] in AWS instance[I have an ip address: example: 5.32.44.55]

The homepage displays great. Rest of the pages shows 404 error

If I update the permalink: It works on basic one : ?page_id=sth

But once I make this with other setting, doesnot work.

Note: The menu link is given in page format: example.com/page

Tried to change it manually, gave all edit access, edited httpd config as well, nothing worked.

The page should load without showing 404 errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Apache's mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: "AllowOverride Always 
Require all granted"

is done. Still nothing is moved

Comment: mod_rewrite is an Apache module and should be enabled in the apache panel. 
As for the conf file, it depends on how the vHost is configured but assuming it is in the default /var/www/html/ folder you need these settings (i.e., AllowOverride All) set for that folder in the Apache main conf file.

Comment: can you share the path? I think I made all the correction like you mentioned but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go here - /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
2. Change the 'AllowOverride None' line in the above section to read 'AllowOverride All'
3. Restart the Apache service